# Multiline bash alias runs out of order

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to write a multiline alias but the order of execution is way off. My alias looks like so:

```
alias test_alias="
echo one
echo two
echo three
echo four
echo five
"
```

When I run the alias I get the following output:

```
$ test_alias
two
three
four
five
one
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the ordered output I would expect?

Here's some bash info:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release
```

Comment: I don't know what's up with your code, but why not just use a function instead?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with either `bash` or `zsh`.  But like @melpomene said, a function would be preferable over an alias here.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://tio.run/##RcxLCoAwDADRfU4RuvcInkWiRiJIU5r4uX0EW3D3mMXMZBJhosVxMOSnUF4nOnYyNoAP6Gze2piAF1HUzA1@a4dU7m3Ts3btF0MC@AcRLw).

Comment: Show output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: @Cyrus posted above

Comment: Weird. Can you run `bash --norc` to get a clean shell, try it again, and copy-paste the entire terminal transcript?

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine how this would happen without, say, overriding `echo` with an implementation that runs in the background, or redirecting stdout to something very unusual.

Comment: @JohnnyMetz, ...if you run `set -x` before expanding that alias, what's logged?

Comment: ...not that multiline aliases are something anyone should ever use; any use case they might serve would be better fulfilled by a function.

Comment: Is that your *exact* alias definition, copy-and-pasted into your question? I'm wondering if there's some subtle difference between what you've shown us in the question and what you're actually doing.

Comment: @KeithThompson that's my exact definition

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the output shows the echos running in the wrong order plus a bunch of other random stuff

Comment: @JohnnyMetz, the details, particularly the "random stuff", matter (if we're going to actually find an explanation rather than just a workaround for the behavior at hand). That is to say: Don't describe it, *show* it.

Comment: ...one might also run the `alias -p` command to determine whether the ordering is broken at definition time or runtime. I *assume* runtime, in which case the output would be unsurprising, but it's worth checking -- we're dealing with a low-probability scenario, after all.

Comment: (If you could reproduce this in http://ideone.com/ or another online interpreter, that would be *ideal* -- that way we could stop trying to bug you with questions, and just fork the interpreter instance and investigate there; note that `shopt -s expand_aliases` needs to be run before aliases can be used in scripts or other noninteractive environments).

Answer (score -1):

It appears a function is a better approach for my use case here:

```
function test_func() {
    echo one
    echo two
    echo three
    echo four
    echo five
}
```

Running the function:

```
$ test_func
one
two
three
four
five
```

If I did want to keep the alias, looks like I just need to move the closing quotes to the end of the last line:

```
alias test_alias="
echo one
echo two
echo three
echo four
echo five"
```

Comment: As an aside, it's good form to use either `test_func() {` (POSIX-standardized syntax) or `function test_func {` (legacy ksh syntax). The hybrid with both the `function` keyword *and* the `()`s is compatible with neither POSIX sh *or* with legacy ksh, so it's worst-of-both-worlds; see also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: I downvoted; the change in the alias should make no difference, and switching to a function, though recommended, should not have made a difference to the reported problem (which no one can reproduce). This is a non-answer.

Comment: @chepner: I considered downvoting as well, but decided not to. This answer doesn't explain what the original problem is, but it does show a solution (using a function) that works. See "*How can I get the ordered output I would expect?*" in the body of the question. (But I'd still like to see more information in the question, particularly the "bunch of other random stuff" the OP alluded to in a comment.)

Comment: The answer isn't going to be useful to anyone else, though, because it doesn't solve a "real" problem. The question should be closed as "cannot reproduced", not answered.

Comment: @chepner moving the double quotes to the end of the last line instead of its own line solved the problem; however, the function is the best solution here IMO

Comment: @JohnnyMetz There's no *reason* it should have solved the problem, as there is no apparent reason for the problem in the first place.

Comment: I do have to agree with chepner here -- without a reproducer for the issue, we have no reason to believe that anyone seeing the same symptom will see it for the same reason, and thus that the same fix will be applicable.